# Wrote code to convert to format CSV, JSON, XML. Also swears at creating JSON. Can it be simplified?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-Process -Name "chrome" | Format-Table Name,ID, StartTime, PagedMemorySize | ConvertTo-Csv | Add-Content -Path c:\Out\demo12.csv 
Get-Process -Name "chrome" | Format-Table Name,ID, StartTime, PagedMemorySize | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path c:\Out\demo12.json
Get-Process -Name "chrome" | Format-Table Name,ID, StartTime, PagedMemorySize | ConvertTo-Xml | Set-Content -Path c:\Out\demo12.xml

WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ```Format-Table``` is for formatting data for *display* purposes (e.g. console / log output). You probably want ```Select-Object``` instead to create *data* suitable for the ```ConvertTo-*``` cmdlets.

Comment: Write a script to get list of process (ex. All chrome process) and put Name, Id, StartTime, PagedMemorySize in CSV/XML/JSON/YAML files where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlet has a maximum [`-Depth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.3#-depth) that:

> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the
> JSON representation. The value can be any number from 0 to 100. The
> default value is 2. ConvertTo-Json emits a warning if the number of
> levels in an input object exceeds this number.

So you just need to set this parameter accodingly to the data that you are trying to save.
I would also bear in mind what @mclayton said in his comment to your question about not using [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.3) in this case.

Comment: Can these three lines be combined?

Comment: Probably they can be combined into one, but I don't know how. Personaly, I would get the data on one sentence and then convert and store it with another three.
`$chromeData=Get-Process -Name "chrome" | Format-Table Name,ID, StartTime, PagedMemorySize; 

$chromeData | ConvertTo-Csv | Add-Content -Path c:\Out\demo12.csv;
$chromeData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 15 | Set-Content -Path c:\Out\demo12.json;
$chromeData | ConvertTo-Xml | Set-Content -Path c:\Out\demo12.xml;`